# contact form 'reply to' not working as planned

Tags: php, email

I want to make emails sent via contact form on my website to appear as being sent from user's mailbox (eg. user specified his email in contact form as 'john1233@gmail.com' - i want this email to be seen as sent from him directly, with proper reply option).

I tried to modify this script on my own, with no success :( I am not very proficient with php, so any help will be much appreciated!!

Here is the script I used:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "my email";

    $email_subject = "mail subject";


   // validation here

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

   // error messages here
    $error_message = "";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

       $email_message .='my html code'
;

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing brace.. are you sure your code is working ?

Comment: As i've seen in codes its Reply-to not Reply-To, maybe its case sensitive, not sure try once :)

Comment: Each of your `$headers` assignments is replacing what the previous line assigned, because you're not appending. And you're not assigning the `Reply-To` or `X-Mailer` headers to any variable at all.

Comment: @AnkitPise Mail headers are not case sensitive.

Comment: also missing `$header` append with `.`

Comment: Yes code works perfectly, I probably messed it up a bit while removing some personal information.. The issue here is only area the email address of the user, rest irrelevant.

Comment: There's no need to use `Reply-to` if it's the same as `From`. Replies are sent to the `From` address by default, and `Reply-to` is only needed to override that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
           "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . 
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar!! working flawlessly now :)